# YouTube API: Get Playlist of a video?

Tags: youtube-data-api

To get the details for a certain video i use:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But there is no information about the playlist this video is in. How can I get this?

Comment: You have a many-to-many relationship here. A video can be on multiple playlists, and a playlist can have multiple videos. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to talk about "the playlist the video is in", because it can be on hundred or even thousands of playlists.

Comment: Thanks. So it's not possible to get a list of all playlists the video is in?

Comment: I quickly scanned the YouTube docs, and no; it doesn't look like you can filter playlists on their items of the time being. I might be wrong, though ;-)